# Opacity affecting the whole content

Tags: css, twitter, opacity

How does twitter implement this kind of transparency ?

[image]

I tried adding opacity to my code but every children element is being affected. what I aim   is somewhat like in the image above. how would I do that? is opacity the right css rule for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `RGBa` instead of `opacity` to achieve this effect. The opacity property forces all child elements to also become transparent, and there are not many simple ways to work around that. RGBa makes the element transparent but all the child elements remain unchanged.

**Example:**

```
div {
   background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5); 
}
```

The first three numbers in RGBa represent the color in RGB values; the fourth represents a transparency, and should be between 0.0 and 1.0 (similar to the opacity property).

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BJgj6/)

[RGB Color Chart](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/)

Answer (score 1):

background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);

http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

Comment: Thanks! this is somehow close to it. but this will do! did you use any generator for this?

Comment: no generator, it is just an rgb triplet, with an alpha value between solid (1) and clear (0) as the fourth value.

Answer (score 0):

CSS opacity will always work that way. You can always use semi-transparent png as a background.